# Error in the link navigation

Tags: html

I am experiencing a navigation error on my site. When you click the nav item for the second time it does not work. e.g. If you click 'Team' it will take you to that section, but once you click a nav item for the second time it is a dead link.

Here is the site - http://evolvedengineering.com.au

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: From JS console: `TypeError: jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function`

Comment: @phts while this is correct, surely this would apply on page load rather than applying only after the first link has been clicked?

Comment: Anyway it's better to create fiddles and try to fix/reproduce such errors in a limited environment rather than finding bugs in a production code on a shipped site

Answer (score 0):

Another JS console error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Related to

```
!function ($) {
    //=================================== scroll  ===================================//

$body.scrollspy({
      target: '#navbar-main',
      offset: navHeight
    })

    $window.on('load', function () {
      $body.scrollspy('refresh')
    })

    $('#navbar-main [href=#]').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
    })


});
```

Obviously something wrong with it. Where is it from?

Maybe should it be like this:

```
!(function ($) {
    //=================================== scroll  ===================================//

    $body.scrollspy({
      target: '#navbar-main',
      offset: navHeight
    });

    $window.on('load', function () {
      $body.scrollspy('refresh')
    });

    $('#navbar-main [href=#]').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
    });

})(jQuery);
```